# Remove special characters except space from a string

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I want to remove special characters except space from a string using a script. For example, `ALBAÃ‘IL` should output as `Albaail` but this is only one example. It can be any other name or word in one or multiple CSV file(s). Am using Visual Studio to process CSV data to SQL Server table.

Comment: If you want to use JavaScript, why do you tag it `vb.net`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Javascript solution: http://lehelk.com/2011/05/06/script-to-remove-diacritics/

It basically uses regular expressions to brute force the conversion from the various diacritical characters to standard ASCII.

It copes with lower case and capital letters, too, so your example would convert to "ALBAAIL".

As others have mentioned, Javascript isn't Visual Studio, or .net, so I don't really know what kind of solution you are really looking for.

**EDIT:**

Okay, so according to your comment, you're coding in VB. That's cool, because I code in VB and have already converted the code I linked to into VB:

```
Public Function ParseTo819Internal(ByVal sendString As String, replaceChar As Char) As String
    Static x As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    If x Is Nothing Then
        x = New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        x.Add("A", "[\u0041\u24B6\uFF21\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u01DE\u1EA2\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F]")
        x.Add("AA", "[\uA732]")
        x.Add("AE", "[\u01FC\u01E2]")
        x.Add("AO", "[\uA734]")
        x.Add("AU", "[\uA736]")
        x.Add("AV", "[\uA738\uA73A]")
        x.Add("AY", "[\uA73C]")
        x.Add("B", "[\u0042\u24B7\uFF22\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u0243\u0182\u0181]")
        x.Add("C", "[\u0043\u24B8\uFF23\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u1E08\u0187\u023B\uA73E]")
        x.Add("D", "[\u0044\u24B9\uFF24\u1E0A\u010E\u1E0C\u1E10\u1E12\u1E0E\u0110\u018B\u018A\u0189\uA779]")
        x.Add("DZ", "[\u01F1\u01C4]")
        x.Add("Dz", "[\u01F2\u01C5]")
        x.Add("E", "[\u0045\u24BA\uFF25\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E]")
        x.Add("F", "[\u0046\u24BB\uFF26\u1E1E\u0191\uA77B]")
        x.Add("G", "[\u0047\u24BC\uFF27\u01F4\u011C\u1E20\u011E\u0120\u01E6\u0122\u01E4\u0193\uA7A0\uA77D\uA77E]")
        x.Add("H", "[\u0048\u24BD\uFF28\u0124\u1E22\u1E26\u021E\u1E24\u1E28\u1E2A\u0126\u2C67\u2C75\uA78D]")
        x.Add("I", "[\u0049\u24BE\uFF29\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197]")
        x.Add("J", "[\u004A\u24BF\uFF2A\u0134\u0248]")
        x.Add("K", "[\u004B\u24C0\uFF2B\u1E30\u01E8\u1E32\u0136\u1E34\u0198\u2C69\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA7A2]")
        x.Add("L", "[\u004C\u24C1\uFF2C\u013F\u0139\u013D\u1E36\u1E38\u013B\u1E3C\u1E3A\u0141\u023D\u2C62\u2C60\uA748\uA746\uA780]")
        x.Add("LJ", "[\u01C7]")
        x.Add("Lj", "[\u01C8]")
        x.Add("M", "[\u004D\u24C2\uFF2D\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u2C6E\u019C]")
        x.Add("N", "[\u004E\u24C3\uFF2E\u01F8\u0143\u1E44\u0147\u1E46\u0145\u1E4A\u1E48\u0220\u019D\uA790\uA7A4]")
        x.Add("NJ", "[\u01CA]")
        x.Add("Nj", "[\u01CB]")
        x.Add("O", "[\u004F\u24C4\uFF2F\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C]")
        x.Add("OI", "[\u01A2]")
        x.Add("OO", "[\uA74E]")
        x.Add("OU", "[\u0222]")
        x.Add("P", "[\u0050\u24C5\uFF30\u1E54\u1E56\u01A4\u2C63\uA750\uA752\uA754]")
        x.Add("Q", "[\u0051\u24C6\uFF31\uA756\uA758\u024A]")
        x.Add("R", "[\u0052\u24C7\uFF32\u0154\u1E58\u0158\u0210\u0212\u1E5A\u1E5C\u0156\u1E5E\u024C\u2C64\uA75A\uA7A6\uA782]")
        x.Add("S", "[\u0053\u24C8\uFF33\u1E9E\u015A\u1E64\u015C\u1E60\u0160\u1E66\u1E62\u1E68\u0218\u015E\u2C7E\uA7A8\uA784]")
        x.Add("T", "[\u0054\u24C9\uFF34\u1E6A\u0164\u1E6C\u021A\u0162\u1E70\u1E6E\u0166\u01AC\u01AE\u023E\uA786]")
        x.Add("TZ", "[\uA728]")
        x.Add("U", "[\u0055\u24CA\uFF35\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244]")
        x.Add("V", "[\u0056\u24CB\uFF36\u1E7C\u1E7E\u01B2\uA75E\u0245]")
        x.Add("VY", "[\uA760]")
        x.Add("W", "[\u0057\u24CC\uFF37\u1E80\u1E82\u0174\u1E86\u1E84\u1E88\u2C72]")
        x.Add("X", "[\u0058\u24CD\uFF38\u1E8A\u1E8C]")
        x.Add("Y", "[\u0059\u24CE\uFF39\u1EF2\u0176\u1EF8\u0232\u1E8E\u0178\u1EF6\u1EF4\u01B3\u024E\u1EFE]")
        x.Add("Z", "[\u005A\u24CF\uFF3A\u0179\u1E90\u017B\u017D\u1E92\u1E94\u01B5\u0224\u2C7F\u2C6B\uA762]")
        x.Add("a", "[\u0061\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u01DF\u1EA3\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250]")
        x.Add("aa", "[\uA733]")
        x.Add("ae", "[\u01FD\u01E3]")
        x.Add("ao", "[\uA735]")
        x.Add("au", "[\uA737]")
        x.Add("av", "[\uA739\uA73B]")
        x.Add("ay", "[\uA73D]")
        x.Add("b", "[\u0062\u24D1\uFF42\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u0180\u0183\u0253]")
        x.Add("c", "[\u0063\u24D2\uFF43\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u1E09\u0188\u023C\uA73F\u2184]")
        x.Add("d", "[\u0064\u24D3\uFF44\u1E0B\u010F\u1E0D\u1E11\u1E13\u1E0F\u0111\u018C\u0256\u0257\uA77A]")
        x.Add("dz", "[\u01F3\u01C6]")
        x.Add("e", "[\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD]")
        x.Add("f", "[\u0066\u24D5\uFF46\u1E1F\u0192\uA77C]")
        x.Add("g", "[\u0067\u24D6\uFF47\u01F5\u011D\u1E21\u011F\u0121\u01E7\u0123\u01E5\u0260\uA7A1\u1D79\uA77F]")
        x.Add("h", "[\u0068\u24D7\uFF48\u0125\u1E23\u1E27\u021F\u1E25\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E96\u0127\u2C68\u2C76\u0265]")
        x.Add("hv", "[\u0195]")
        x.Add("i", "[\u0069\u24D8\uFF49\u0129\u012B\u012D\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131]")
        x.Add("j", "[\u006A\u24D9\uFF4A\u0135\u01F0\u0249]")
        x.Add("k", "[\u006B\u24DA\uFF4B\u1E31\u01E9\u1E33\u0137\u1E35\u0199\u2C6A\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA7A3]")
        x.Add("l", "[\u006C\u24DB\uFF4C\u0140\u013A\u013E\u1E37\u1E39\u013C\u1E3D\u1E3B\u017F\u0142\u019A\u026B\u2C61\uA749\uA781\uA747]")
        x.Add("lj", "[\u01C9]")
        x.Add("m", "[\u006D\u24DC\uFF4D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u0271\u026F]")
        x.Add("n", "[\u006E\u24DD\uFF4E\u01F9\u0144\u1E45\u0148\u1E47\u0146\u1E4B\u1E49\u019E\u0272\u0149\uA791\uA7A5]")
        x.Add("nj", "[\u01CC]")
        x.Add("o", "[\u006F\u24DE\uFF4F\u1ED3\u1ED1\u1ED7\u1ED5\u1E4D\u022D\u1E4F\u014D\u1E51\u1E53\u014F\u022F\u0231\u022B\u1ECF\u0151\u01D2\u020D\u020F\u01A1\u1EDD\u1EDB\u1EE1\u1EDF\u1EE3\u1ECD\u1ED9\u01EB\u01ED\u01FF\u0254\uA74B\uA74D\u0275]")
        x.Add("oi", "[\u01A3]")
        x.Add("ou", "[\u0223]")
        x.Add("oo", "[\uA74F]")
        x.Add("p", "[\u0070\u24DF\uFF50\u1E55\u1E57\u01A5\u1D7D\uA751\uA753\uA755]")
        x.Add("q", "[\u0071\u24E0\uFF51\u024B\uA757\uA759]")
        x.Add("r", "[\u0072\u24E1\uFF52\u0155\u1E59\u0159\u0211\u0213\u1E5B\u1E5D\u0157\u1E5F\u024D\u027D\uA75B\uA7A7\uA783]")
        x.Add("s", "[\u0073\u24E2\uFF53\u015B\u1E65\u015D\u1E61\u0161\u1E67\u1E63\u1E69\u0219\u015F\u023F\uA7A9\uA785\u1E9B]")
        x.Add("t", "[\u0074\u24E3\uFF54\u1E6B\u1E97\u0165\u1E6D\u021B\u0163\u1E71\u1E6F\u0167\u01AD\u0288\u2C66\uA787]")
        x.Add("tz", "[\uA729]")
        x.Add("u", "[\u0075\u24E4\uFF55\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289]")
        x.Add("v", "[\u0076\u24E5\uFF56\u1E7D\u1E7F\u028B\uA75F\u028C]")
        x.Add("vy", "[\uA761]")
        x.Add("w", "[\u0077\u24E6\uFF57\u1E81\u1E83\u0175\u1E87\u1E85\u1E98\u1E89\u2C73]")
        x.Add("x", "[\u0078\u24E7\uFF58\u1E8B\u1E8D]")
        x.Add("y", "[\u0079\u24E8\uFF59\u1EF3\u0177\u1EF9\u0233\u1E8F\u1EF7\u1E99\u1EF5\u01B4\u024F\u1EFF]")
        x.Add("z", "[\u007A\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763]")
    End If
    For Each keyIn In x.Keys
        sendString = Regex.Replace(sendString, x(keyIn), keyIn)
    Next

    'Having replaced all recognised diacritical characters with plain letters, replace all remaining non-IBM819 characters with question marks
    sendString = Regex.Replace(sendString, "[^0-9a-zA-Z !""#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ\s]", replaceChar)

    Return sendString
End Function
```

This is a function to sanitise our input into [IBM819](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) format for our database so in addition to stripping out all of the accented characters, it also checks for any remaining non-compatible characters and replaces them with the `replaceChar`variable. I'm not too familiar with regular expressions, to be honest, but I think that if you use a value of `String.Empty` for `replaceChar` then it will simply delete all remaining unrecognised characters.

If you're converting to straight ASCII or to a different codepage than IBM819, you will need to make alterations to the final regex.

Comment: I apologize. Am new to this so wasn't sure how to word the solution I am looking for.  I am using Visual Studio and if VB Net is the correct terminology then I need to find a solution for this environment.  I just met with the AS400 programmer and he is telling I just need to ensure no accents are in the names. So I guess I really need to remove accents, ALBAÃ‘IL to ABLAAIL.  Any suggestions and thanks in advance.

Comment: Have added a VB solution for you. ' should be a valid character in most languages, though, so if you don't want it you will need to remove it manually. I would check with your programmer to see if he can give you a complete list of compatible characters. I'm going home now so I won't be able to respond for an hour, but I shall try and remember to check back when I get home, or tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

How about you use an asp.net code behind method to handle the conversion from CSV rather than try to do it in Javascript? using .net, you could add different validation and cleansing rules as needed using a factory class pattern.